# How do I list ejabberd users by registration date?

Tags: ejabberd

A spammer found my private ejd server and registered a few thousand users. I want to get rid of them all without causing collateral damage to other users. Is there a way to get a list of users that registered on a certain date or range of dates? I didn't see anything in ejabberdctl, and the relevant logs have expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a list of users that registered on a certain date or range of dates?

Unfortunately, no.

But usually spammers use automated tools, so, maybe you can find some pattern in the usernames of spam accounts.

Also, look at their rosters, maybe the spam accounts have some common contacts. Then you can search the roster table with "ejabberdctl process_rosteritems list ..." to detect all spam accounts.